# multi threading using an iframe

Tags: javascript, multithreading, iframe

I am trying to simulate multi threading using an iframe but I have come across a situation which I do not know if it actually utilizes the iframe process (thread) on its own.

For instance, If I call a method which lays inside an iframe, will it run using the thread created by the iframe or will it run using the main parent window thread?

If it is the latter, then is it possible to change the scope so that the iframe calls the method (so that the program uses a different thread from that of the parent window)

EDIT:
Maybe I should have been more clear on this but I do not want to use WebWorkers simply because I do not have access to the DOM elements.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run some background tasks just use [WebWorkers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Workers).

Generally you don't need to multi thread js code. You should use event loops instead.

Comment: I agree about event loops, threads don't add processing power, they are just a means to partition execution of code. Google how node.js is being used to understand the power of eventing over threading.

Comment: @KevinHakanson yes I agree. But the main use for threads is running long pieces of computation in the background. You can't use event loops for long-running pieces of computation, you would throw them in a new process. In the browser we can't create processes so we use web workers

Comment: My application is a little bit more complex than just computations. I want to be able to have multiple threads handling SVG elements (scale,translate,rotate,etc.) within the parent window.

Comment: @Raynos Because what the application does is that it gets a series of drawn svg elements from a database and applies them on an svg document (using Raphael.js). It takes along time when the svg paths are complex and in greater number. I just wanted to reduce the loading time.

Comment: You dont need threads in javascript code, except for when you do. Currently the DOM, canvas, and AudioContext are only available in the main thread. Fancy graphics and audio compete. Users forgive a glitched frame on a monitor but not glitched audio. And glitched frames are unnaceptable in VR. If a browser was a person it would never be able to walk and chew gum.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Using web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_web_workers) from the MDN docs.

> The Worker interface spawns real OS-level threads, and concurrency can
>   cause interesting effects in your code if you aren't careful. However,
>   in the case of web workers, the carefully controlled communication
>   points with other threads means that it's actually very hard to cause
>   concurrency problems.  There's no access to non-thread safe components
>   or the DOM and you have to pass specific data in and out of a thread
>   through serialized objects.  So you have to work really hard to cause
>   problems in your code.

John Resig wrote [Computing with JavaScript Web Workers](http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/)n back in 2009 on this topic.  However, according to [When can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=worker), there is no IE support until IE10 so it may not fit your needs.