# how to Load Iframe using webworker without hampering main angular app

Tags: angular, iframe, web-worker

I have an Angular application that includes an Iframe which is dashboard UI.Since Iframe is a rich with multiple ui components,Complete loading process of actual UI including the Iframe is taking too long.I am seeking help here to know if there is any way to load the Iframe with the help of web workers/any alternative approach, which can run parallel without affecting main app in browser.

Using Angular 15.

There are few threads relating to this issue .But none of them gave a valid answer . Please Help me.
Here are the threads i already checked.

[Will a browser give an iframe a separate thread for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510483/will-a-browser-give-an-iframe-a-separate-thread-for-javascript)

[Running iframe with large application in background without affecting main application,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845349/running-iframe-with-large-application-in-background-without-affecting-main-appli)

[multi threading using an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967201/multi-threading-using-an-iframe)

Comment: You want a ServiceWorker, not a WebWorker.

Comment: Can you please give me any pointers to proceed .AFAIK Service workers helps in caching the application. Wondering how iframe loading can be handled using service worker.